# error: class, interface, or enum expected - occurs nearly after every certain line

Tags: java

I have tried looking up what it could be and have spent days looking at it trying to figure out what I did wrong. It happens on almost every line after the 30th one begging with " public static int[] populate(int count, int range) {". I'm pretty sure its a single thing causing these issues but I just don't see what it is.

```
    public class PerformanceComparisonPre {
/**
  This program compares the performance between linear and binary search algorithm
*/

public static int linearSearch(int[] list, int key) {
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length;  i++) {
        if (list[i] == key) {
            return key;
        }
    }
}

public static int binarySearch(int[] list, int key) { 
    int low = 0;
    int high = list.length - 1;
    while (high >= low) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2; 
        System.out.printf("%d %d %d\n", low, mid, high);
        if (key < list[mid])
            high = mid - 1;
        else if (key == list[mid])
            return mid;
        else
            low = mid + 1;
        }
    return -1;
    }
}
public static int[] populate(int count, int range) {
    int[] result = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        result[i]=i;}
    return result[];
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long t1, t2;
    int result;
    int[] test1 = populate(10000000, 400);

    // time the binary search
    t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    java.util.Arrays.sort(test1); // don't forget binarySearch requires a sorted array
    t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int sortingTime = (int)(t2 - t1);

    t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    result = binarySearch(test1, 100);
    t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int binarySearchTime = (int)(t2 - t1);

    // time the linear search
    t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    result = linearSearch(test1, 100);
    t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int linearSearchTime = (int)(t2 - t1);

    System.out.printf("sorting: %d millisecond, binary search: %d millisecond, linear search: %d millisecond\n", sortingTime, binarySearchTime, linearSearchTime);
}
```

Comment: put } in the last line. You haven't closed brace for class

Comment: Your `binarySearch` method contains two `{` characters and three `}` characters.  General principle - when you get an error like this, look at what comes _before_ it.

Comment: Also, if you use `{` and `}` characters for EVERY branch and EVERY loop, you're much  less likely to run into this kind of difficulty.

Comment: And if you use tooling that autoindents for you, this sort of problem becomes immediately obvious.

Comment: I have voted to close this as "caused by a typo".  This is the correct thing to do when a question is the result of a typo.  This question should _not_ be answered, and nor should others like it.

Comment: Use some IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse, it will clearly show you what and where is the problem for your typo mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove extra closing brackets at the end of your binarySearch method.
2. change result[]; to result; at populate method.
3. add one closing brackets at the very end of your code.

Answer (score -1):

```
package org.training.zoo;
```

public class PerformanceComparisonPre {
    /**
     * This program compares the performance between linear and binary search
     * algorithm
     */

```
public static int linearSearch(int[] list, int key) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i] == key) {
            return key;
        }
    }
    return -1; // just a guess
}

public static int binarySearch(int[] list, int key) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = list.length - 1;
    while (high >= low) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        System.out.printf("%d %d %d\n", low, mid, high);
        if (key < list[mid])
            high = mid - 1;
        else if (key == list[mid])
            return mid;
        else
            low = mid + 1;
    }
    return -1;
}

public static int[] populate(int count, int range) {
    int[] result = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        result[i] = i;
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long t1, t2;
    int result;
    int[] test1 = populate(10000000, 400);

    // time the binary search
    t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    java.util.Arrays.sort(test1); // don't forget binarySearch requires a
                                    // sorted array
    t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int sortingTime = (int) (t2 - t1);

    t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    result = binarySearch(test1, 100);
    t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int binarySearchTime = (int) (t2 - t1);

    // time the linear search
    t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    result = linearSearch(test1, 100);
    t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int linearSearchTime = (int) (t2 - t1);

    System.out.printf("sorting: %d millisecond, binary search: %d millisecond, linear search: %d millisecond\n",
            sortingTime, binarySearchTime, linearSearchTime);
}
```

}